# Does the cloth jacket on my wiring contain asbestos?

Tags: electrical, wiring, asbestos

I grabbed this photo from [another Q&A](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/57487/cloth-covered-nm-questions) of the same wiring in my house.  It is labelled Diamond DTX NM 600V.  It looks like cloth wrapped wiring.  Does anyone know anything about asbestos with it?  I could not easily find this information myself.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This cloth covered wire is very common and not an asbestos product. With that said in some cases where ceiling were sprayed with popcorn texture or the wire pulled through an area with asbestos the cloth holds onto the fibers. We tested some for a owner that wanted everything tested and did get a positive on one or 2 sections but the insulation on the wires and the cloth itself are not asbestos.